# openvpn - ifconfig parameter

Tags: vpn, openvpn, configuration, ifconfig

What does `ifconfig` parameter in openvpn configuration file mean?
Here is an example file:

```
dev tun0
proto udp
comp-lzo
port 5073
remote 172.16.23.73 5073
ifconfig 172.17.3.41 172.17.3.43
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From OpenVPNs own documentation:

```
# 10.1.0.2 is our local VPN endpoint (home).
# 10.1.0.1 is our remote VPN endpoint (office).
ifconfig 10.1.0.2 10.1.0.1
```

In other words this is when you want your VPN **clients** to assign their own VPN IP address.

The client will in my example have the IP address `10.1.0.2` and the VPN gateway will have the IP address `10.1.0.1`.

Found it on my Ubuntu server under
`/usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/static-home.conf`

---

The alternative is using `client-config-dir <path>` in OpenVPN servers master file and let all clients connect to the server using a client certificate with unique CommonName in the certificate.

Lets say you have setup `client-config-dir` to point to the subdirectory `ccd`.

You can then create a file with a name matching the CommonName in each client certificate that contains the line `ifconfig-push <IP address> <subnet mask>`. Using my example above:

```
ifconfig-push 10.1.0.2 255.255.255.0
```

This assumes you have a line in the servers master config file that contains the line:

```
server 10.1.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this!

Answer (score 0):

It is to give the same VPN IP to the client. Read the Master config file. These details are already in the config file and commented out.